# Connect HTML page with Elasticsearch using Python flask

Tags: python, html, elasticsearch, flask

I am new to web development. I am trying to create a web page which will display index from elastic search database. I am using python flask for backend.
I see html page and python console shows index. 
But I am not able to fetch index from HTML page.

I am not sure what could be the issue

Python code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

app = Flask(__name__)
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

doc1 = {"food": "Japanese", "spice_level": "moderate"}
doc2 = {"food": "Italian", "spice_level": "mild"}
doc3 = {"food": "Indian", "spice_level": "spicy"}
es.index(index="food", doc_type="spice_level", id=1, body=doc2)
resp = es.get(index="food", doc_type="spice_level", id=1)
print(resp)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

  app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

if __name__ == '__main__':

 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <BODY bgcolor="cyan">
    <form method="GET" action="/dashboard">
     <center>
      <H1>Database UI </H1> <br>
      search here <input type = "text" name= "index" /> <br>
      <input type = "submit">
     </center>
    </form>
  </BODY>
</html>
```

Whenever I type a index name and click on search button, page gives me error as :

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I cannot see any other error then this, and it's really difficult to debug with less information about error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the indentation of your python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. why your `/dashboard` return 404 ?

   because lack of view function to response.

   `app.route('/dashboard', methods=['GET', 'POST'])` is invalid.
2. How to access `/dashboard` of elascticsearch ?

   In your case, the simplest way is modify the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <BODY bgcolor="cyan">
    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:9200/dashboard">
     <center>
      <H1>Database UI </H1> <br>
      search here <input type = "text" name= "index" /> <br>
      <input type = "submit">
     </center>
    </form>
  </BODY>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use this here? for Parse data from html to python code you need to have POST inside @app.route like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():

    return render_template('index.html')
```

if you want to pase data into index.html you can use this here:

> somedata = "variable string"
>
> render_template('index.html', somedata=somedata)

inside index.html do {{ somedata }}

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <BODY bgcolor="cyan">
    <form method="POST" action="">
     <center>
      <H1>Database UI </H1> <br>
      <!-- it will show (variable string) -->
      {{ somedata }}
      search here <input type = "text" name= "index" /> <br>
      <input type = "submit">
     </center>
    </form>
  </BODY>
</html>
```

happy codeing.